# recursive function call and/or loop repeats not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function should produce yes or no user-input questions for a list of actions and a corresponding list of choices. It returns a list of boolean values.
E.g. ['watch', 'play', ...] and ['footbal', 'sports', ...]
=> Do you watch footbal? _ etc.

Problem:

The function iterates too often, when wrong inputs are made by the user - although those are seperately handled as you can see!

I determined that with single element lists this code works fine. So here my code. I know print-debugging, and I´m a bloody beginner.

```
def yes_or_no(action, choices, *argv):
    decisions = []
    #remember previous decisions (in case an error occured)
    for arg in argv:
        decisions = arg
    print('choices: ', choices)
    print('decisions: ', decisions)
    for choice in choices:
        print(choice)
        decision = input('Do you want to {} {}? Plase, type [y/n]: '.format(action, choice))
        try:
            decision = str(decision)
            if decision == 'y':
                decisions.append(True)
                pass
            elif decision == 'n':
                decisions.append(False)
                pass
            else:
                print('\nYour input was neither y = \'yes\' nor n = \'no\'.\nOnce again.')
                new_choices = choices[choices.index(choice):]
                yes_or_no(action, new_choices, decisions)
        except ValueError:
            print('\nYour input was neither y = \'yes\' nor n = \'no\'.\nOnce again.')
            new_choices = choices[choices.index(choice):]               
            yes_or_no(action, new_choices, decisions)
    print(decisions)
    return (decisions)
```

Well, when I first enter an invalid input, the recursion starts, but the for choice in choices iterates 2(!) times altough there is just one element in this list!

Therefore I added the print() statements to the code to see this - it´s insane!

Here are my results from the command line:

```
choices:  ['football', 'sports']
decisions:  []
watch
Do you want to watch football? Plase, type [y/n]: sure

Your input was neither y = 'yes' nor n = 'no'.
Once again.
choices:  ['football', 'sports']
decisions:  []
football
Do you want to watch football? Plase, type [y/n]: n
sports
Do you want to watch sports? Plase, type [y/n]: y
sports
Do you want to watch sports? Plase, type [y/n]: y
[False, True, True]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you keep iterating through `choices` when you give wrong `decision` before the last element of `choices`. The solution here should be adding `return` statement after recalling the function. Your snippet updated with the statement would then look like:

```py
def yes_or_no(action, choices, *argv):
    decisions = []
    #remember previous decisions (in case an error occured)
    for arg in argv:
        decisions = arg
    print('choices: ', choices)
    print('decisions: ', decisions)
    for choice in choices:
        print(choice)
        decision = input('Do you want to {} {}? Plase, type [y/n]: '.format(action, choice))
        try:
            decision = str(decision)
            if decision == 'y':
                decisions.append(True)
                pass
            elif decision == 'n':
                decisions.append(False)
                pass
            else:
                print('\nYour input was neither y = \'yes\' nor n = \'no\'.\nOnce again.')
                new_choices = choices[choices.index(choice):]
                return yes_or_no(action, new_choices, decisions)
        except ValueError:
            print('\nYour input was neither y = \'yes\' nor n = \'no\'.\nOnce again.')
            new_choices = choices[choices.index(choice):]               
            return yes_or_no(action, new_choices, decisions)
    print(decisions)
    return (decisions)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, it´s me again** - I just couldn´t sign back in to my quickly created account with fake-mail :P

I received a helpful answer within a couple of minutes and therefore I just wanted to share my final solution to this recursion which handles 'yes or no'-questions that are generated by two lists handed over to the function.

```
def yes_or_no(action, choices, *argv):

    error_message = '\nYour input was neither y = \'yes\' nor n = \'no\'.\nOnce again.\n'
    decisions = []

    #remember previous decisions (in case an error occured)
    for arg in argv:
        decisions = arg

    for choice in choices:
        decision = input('Do you want to {} {}? Plase, type [y/n]: '.format(action, choice))

        try:
            decision = str(decision)
            if decision == 'y':
                decisions.append(True)
            elif decision == 'n':
                decisions.append(False)
            else:
                print(error_message)
                decisions = yes_or_no(action, choices[choices.index(choice):], decisions)
                break
        except ValueError:
            print(error_message)
            decisions = yes_or_no(action, choices[choices.index(choice):], decisions)
            break

    return (decisions)
```

**Résumé:** This solution to the motivated problem ('yes or no'-question-handling) likely aint´t the most efficient one - but it´s comprehensive and easily applied to any problem of this kind.
As you may have recognized I didn´t use the suggested 'return' since 'break' causes the same effect because there is just one (!) looping recursion ('for choice in choices:') to break. I preferred 'break' over 'return' because I think it´s technically faster resolved by the compiler.

Downside: So far just one downside came to my mind. In case of many invalid inputs - with many I mean millions or more - this recursion will need more and more storage space. But I guess, that´s well known for recursions. ;-)